# Flask cpanel godaddy server

Tags: python, flask, cpanel, godaddy-api

A website has been developed on a local ubuntu machine using python flask. The website runs fine on ubuntu at 127.0.0.1:5000. This website is supposed to go live on a godaddy server for which there is cpanel access. How to do it?

Comment: You also need to get it ready for production. You shouldnt just deploy it and run it like you would locally - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/

Comment: this article is huge. can you be more specific please, which section?

Comment: sounds like you'd be using the self hosted option and then you need to choose which one suits the server and which one you want to go with.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a shared hosting solution, Answer to your question is NO, you can't do it. In a shared hosting environment Godaddy using only a PHP Stack. so you won't be able to use python there. Either go with VPS and configure your server. or go with a cloud service provider like Digital ocean, AWS, Linode etc.,

Comment: it is possible to login to the godaddy server via ssh, install python3 and execute the code there locally. the server is on linux millenium. not enough?

Comment: Yes, if you have access to the ssh, you can do that. Then you need to use Ngnix or wsgi mod to properly make it production-ready. again the backup of the server, load balancing all the things you need to take care of. I would suggest go with a digital ocean, or aws it's easy compared to this.

Answer (score 0):

If your CPanel has the "Setup Python App" option (it's CloudLinux-based), you can try to deploy there.

I had a problem where only the root URL would work and all other routes returned 404.

Add the following to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE]
```

Got this info from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971427/10122266

Apologies that I couldn't add this as a comment as I do not have sufficient rights yet. But this solution worked for me and it would be a pitty if this little gem is hidden from those who may arrive here.

So would appreciate if this post is not deleted.